# Login fail with low graphics then crash?

Tags: login, power-management, root, login-screen

I was using Transmission to download some stuff, when I got a notification that there was only 800 MB of free space left.

I soon rebooted, only to find out, that i could not login again. I would get an error stating, that the default configuration had changed for "gnome-power-manager" and to contact my system-administrator, though i am the sysadmin.  Every time i tried to login it would fail and the whole thing was in low graphics mode.

So my question is if there is a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your HD is too full for its own good. You can break in through recovery mode and delete a few things in a few simple steps:

1. Hold the left shift key when your
   BIOS screen shows up. Keep holding
   it until you're given a GRUB menu
   screen.
2. Select the first recovery mode option.
3. When given the choice, select the root console option.
4. You're now in single user text mode. You can move around and (provided your user files aren't encrypted) you can delete, add/remove packages, etc. This should give you enough time to delete a few non-essential things (I'd free up a couple of gigabytes to be sure).

   You can also always move them off to a USB disk but I'm not sure if they auto-mount in single user mode so you might have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Once logged into a terminal, as per qbi's post, you can clear out your package cache to free up some space:

`sudo apt-get clean`

When apt downloads packages it caches copies of them in `/var/cache/apt/`, this command will clean out the package cache.

You can use `du -h /var/cache/apt` before and after clearing the cache, to see how much space you have left before and after.

You can also run `df -h` to see how much space you have on all mounted devices, ie your hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like your hard drive has no (or too less) free space. Usually this leads to some strange behavior in some software. You can try to go a virtual terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and enter your username and password. Now it should open a shell. If you are familiar with it, you can browse around, look for large files and move them away or delete them.

If it doesn't work or you're unfamiliar with a shell, you can also use some live CD. I would suggest [Knoppix](http://knoppix.net/). You download the image, burn it on CD and start the CD. It starts some Linux environment with a graphical mode. There you can browse your hard drive and also move away/delete unneeded files. If there is more free space your problems will probably go away.